# How to style items in a JavaFx TableView

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView Column set up as follows, with some text in a Text node. I wanted to style up the text, but the only css property being picked up is the ***italics***. How can I associate the text with other properties such as **color**.

I've tried `text.getStyleClass().add("table-text-allign-top-left");` but only italics gets picked up.

I'd also like to add some kind of spacing, like **padding**, but I don't know how to add such to an item in a TableCell.
The other problem is how to **align** items: to the left' right in a TableCell.

Would appreciate it a lot if anyone could help. Thank you all in advance.

This is an extract of the TableView:

```
clientNames.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<NewClientPOJO, String>, TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String> call(TableColumn<NewClientPOJO, String> param) {
                final TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String> cell = new TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String>() {
                    private Text text;
                    private Text emails;
                    private Text emails2;

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            text = new Text(item.toString());

                            // Setting the wrapping width to the Text
                            text.setWrappingWidth(410);
                            text.getStyleClass().add("table-text-allign-top-left");

                            emails = new Text("Good DW TV");
                            emails.getStyleClass().add("lower");

                            emails2 = new Text("Scandinavia - Lines cold weather");
                            emails2.getStyleClass().add("lower");

                            VBox vbTable = new VBox();
                            vbTable.getChildren().add(text);
                            vbTable.getChildren().add(emails);
                            vbTable.getChildren().add(emails2);

                            setGraphic(vbTable);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should show the css file as well.  [This tutorial might help](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm#sthref14).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2855515/brian) for the reply. I got it to work by changing the Node from Text to a Label. The Label picks up the style class.